# Nginx does not use the given directory (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, nginx, webserver, nginx-config, nginx-location

**Hi there,**
I am quite new to Nginx on Mac OS. I've got a problem. When I put in a file path for a host in my nginx.conf file, it never changes something when I open the website. Nginx always chooses to show me the index.html file from the root directory (opt/homebrew/var/www), even if I put in another directory, for example a folder with a html file on the desktop. I tried changing the file permissions or the owner but nothing does work. I am using Nginx on Mac OS 14.2.1 and installed it via Homebrew.
(I changed domain names, certain file paths and a few other things to example.de and  `for safety reasons)`

**This is my nginx.config:**

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;


#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;


#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Sendfile settings
    sendfile        on;

    # Connection timeouts
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # Server block for HTTP (Port 80)
    server {rewrite ^(/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*) $1 break; # managed by Certbot

rewrite ^(/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*) $1 break; # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.test.example.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = test.example.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name test.example.de www.test.example.de;


        root /Users/laurinbraeunig/Desktop/Server2;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Custom error pages
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root html;
        }

        # PHP processing
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/<Code>{default_type text/plain;return 200 <code>;} # managed by Certbot

location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/<code>{default_type text/plain;return 200 <code>;} # managed by Certbot

}

    # Server block for HTTPS (Port 443)
    server {rewrite ^(/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*) $1 break; # managed by Certbot

rewrite ^(/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*) $1 break; # managed by Certbot


        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name test.example.de www.test.example.de;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        root html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Custom error pages
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root html;
        }

        # PHP processing
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }


location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/<code>{default_type text/plain;return 200 <code>;} # managed by Certbot

location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/<code>{default_type text/plain;return 200 <code>;} # managed by Certbot

}

include servers/*;
}
```

I was hoping, that I could change the root directory of my Nginx Server to another path or use multiple folders for multiple websites / hosts.

Thank you for your help! :)

Laurin

Comment: You seem to have a `server` block for port 80 and another `server` block for port 443. You have changed the `root` statement in the first block only.